# Grails: User evaluator for Commentable with Spring Security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to use the commentable plugin with Spring Security.

I can't manage to write the right

grails.commentable.poster.evaluator

I tried {User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)},
 but from the CommentController, both User and springSecurity seems unaccessible.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `springSecurityService.principal.id` since there's no dependency injection field for `springSecurityService` it can't work, so you need to call what `springSecurityService.principal.id` calls - `org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication.principal.id`

To fix the problem with User, you'll need the full class name with package. So combined, this should be

```
{com.yourcompany.yourapp.User.get(org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication.principal.id)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the very quick answer. 
In the meantime, I wrote a small plugin that adds a getCurrentUser to each controller. Then I use the currentUser in the evaluator. It seems to work

Is that a bad idea? (I am new to both Groovy and Grails, so wouldn't know if it is an anti-idiom to add this kind of methods)

Comment: That reminded me that there's already a `getPrincipal()` method added by Spring Security Core, so that would shorten the call to `com.yourcompany.yourapp.User.get(principal.id)`, but it would be better to also have a `getCurrentUser` method - I'll add that for the next release.

Answer (score 3):

I adapted [Burt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542361/2648) such that it doesn't throw an exception if nobody is logged in

```
grails.commentable.poster.evaluator = {

    def principal = org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication?.principal

    if (principal?.hasProperty('id')) {

        def currentUserId = principal.id
        if (currentUserId) {
            com.yourcompany.yourapp.User.get(currentUserId)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works with the rateable plugin too. ... but it still threw an exception when no user is logged in. I.e. No [grails.rateable.rater.evaluator] setting defined or the evaluator doesn't evaluate to an entity

Comment: @10ToedSloth thanks, I've fixed that (4 years later)