# Commentable plug-in with Spring Security LDAP

Tags: grails-plugin, spring-ldap

I'm trying to get the commentable plug-in running with the spring security framework ldap plugin from Burt Beckwith.

I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541142/grails-user-evaluator-for-commentable-with-spring-security-plugin).

The only difference seems to be that I'm using LDAP and the LDAP user details don't have an id, or I'm not seeing it.

I've tried setting the grails.commentable.poster.evaluator to

```
{com.companyname.sec.User.get(org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication.principal.id)}
```

and also to

```
{com.companyname.sec.User.get(principal.id)}
```

Both of these were suggested in the other issue I referenced above.  What I get is the error below:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl
```

Possible solutions: dn

This seems to suggest using the dn field, but since that's a string, and the id is a Long, I don't think that's the right option.  So, is there a way to configure the grails.commentable.poster.evaluator to get these two plug-ins to work together, or do I need to modify one of them to get a compatible type (i.e. change the commentable plug-in to use a String, and then grab the username from the LDAP user details.)?

Answer (score 1):

Not using the commentable but the spring-security-ldap plugin.

For me this really simple copy&paste solution worked:

[Solution on Grails Jira by Burt](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYLDAP-5)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{com.companyname.sec.User.findByUsername(principal.username)}
```

or

```
{com.companyname.sec.User.findByUsername(org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication.principal.username)}
```

Answer (score 0):

That gives me the following error:

```
org.grails.comments.CommentException: No [grails.commentable.poster.evaluator] setting defined or the evaluator doesn't evaluate to an entity. Please define the evaluator correctly in grails-app/conf/Config.groovy or ensure commenting is secured via your security rules
```

I read that to mean there is no findByUsername method.  So, were you suggesting I create that method in order to get at an id value?  And I assume correspondingly, that means I need to insert the ldap users into the database in order to generate an id.

Comment: After digging some more, I ended up modifying the Commentable plug-in.  Seems like the only solutions were to either persist my ldap users to the database to generate an id, or modify the Commentable plug-in to work using usernames rather than id's.  I chose the latter option, simply because it was a relatively trivial change.